# How to disable history in jGRASP

Tags: jgrasp

Okay, stupid question. Every time I open jGRASP, all the files that were open during the previous session are opened automatically, I have to close them one by one. How can I disable this option/annoyance?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can do: "File" > "Close All".